# Why am I getting different prediction result after every run?

Tags: lstm, training, prediction, validation

I have a simple lstm model

```
model =Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(n_input,n_features)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.summary()
```

on which I train and test on the same data but each time I am getting different prediction. Why?

If the model parameters and train and test are same why the prediction is changing on every run?

If the results are not reproducible what is the point of training and testing lstm model?

the rmse value is almost similar but the predicted values are way off on each run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you specify the random seed anywhere in your code? If you don't, that might be the explanation why your RMSE value differs on each run for your train/test datasets.

You could use the [`set_random_seed()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed) function to set the random seed and have your training be more deterministic. You can also use [`enable_op_determinism()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/enable_op_determinism) to make it even more deterministic, but the training speed will suffer as a result.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed(1)
tf.config.experimental.enable_op_determinism()
```

`utils.set_random_seed()` will automatically set the seed of [`random.seed()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.seed) and [`numpy.random.seed()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.seed.html) as you can see in the linked documentation, so you don't need to import and set those.

On a second note, did you split the train/test set ahead of training or do you use the built-in functions of Tensorflow/Keras to do this? If so, the data split will vary based on the random seed as well.